# Rails automatic generation of "Create" hash in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I'm not exactly sure what is going on when I send a request to my rails API, but I'm getting some weird generation of data.

When I generated a `Model` and `Controller` and make network requests to create that object with JSON, I will write a JSON string that only contains the parameters for the creation at the root of the hash. Then I create it like so:

```
Model.new(params[:model])
```

To me, this was weird, because I never sent a hash with a key 'model', nor did I wrap my parameters hash with the key 'model'.

When I view the parameters for the network call, I see a hash with all of my parameters, exactly as I sent them, but the parameters hash now includes, a seemingly automatically generated hash with the key 'model' and the value being my original parameters hash.

To me, that means that Rails is generating that at some point. However, it seemed to work fine, so I didn't worry too much.

The problem is that I now have a different API with a `Model`, but it isn't automatically generating the inner hash. I then tried just using `params` on my `Model`, but it complains:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: format, controller, action):
```

I'm not sure what is going on at all, or how to fix it, other than assigning the parameters individually, rather than passing a `params` hash directly or wrapping my original network call with a `model` hash.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `attr_accessible` to your model for the elements you are passing in Model.new
Let's say you have columns `name` and `size` in your model. Then you should put something like this:

```
attr_accessible :name, :size
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have that for both models. I can use any other general method in a generic format, except for create, as it doesn't generate the extra hash.

Comment: Can you paste first line of the rails development console log, the one which contains all attributes passed in a request?

Comment: It's RestClient. This is an API.

Comment: Can you post the link to a screenshot?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31896/discussion-between-rileye-and-ermin-dedovic)